# pass params to js function in polymer view

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymer

i have a polymer paper-checkbox, which triggers js function with on-change attribute.

my-component.html:

```
<paper-checkbox on-change="{{ boxChange }}"></paper-checkbox>
```

my-component.js:

```
Polymer('my-component', {
    boxChange: function(event, detail, sender) {
      ...
    }
});
```

is there a way to pass my own params to boxChange function? (other than event, detail, sender)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no. One way of getting around this is to add data-... attributes to your element and get them from the sender in your function.

```
<paper-checkbox on-change="{{ boxChange }}" data-arg1="test"></paper-checkbox>

Polymer('my-component', {
    boxChange: function(event, detail, sender) {
        var arg1 = sender.getAttribute("data-arg1");
    }
});
```